# Random Skype Disk I/O Errors

Tags: windows-7, skype

#### The Problem:

For a couple months now, my girlfriend has been receiving Disk I/O errors on Skype that cause the application to crash. She has tried quite a few solutions available online, but none have rectified the problem.

Interestingly, the crash does not occur on login, as many users have reported, but seems to occur sporadically, happening a few times in a day before disappearing altogether for another week.

The error itself looks like this:

[image: Disk I/O Error]

Is there anything else that can be done to stop this error and the resulting crash?

#### Things we have tried:

- Restarted Skype
- Restarted Computer
- Uninstalled and Installed various versions of Skype including 4.2, 5.6, 6.1, and 6.11
- Tried deleting all user files following [this guide](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10143/why-do-i-get-a-disk-i-o-error-when-i-try-to-sign-in-to-skype-for-windows-desktop).
- Tried deleting user files, and rebooting
- Tried deleting user files, uninstalling Skype, and rebooting
- Tried deleting user files, uninstalling Skype, deleting the entire Skype folder under appdata/roaming, and rebooting
- Tried running Skype as administrator as per [this answer](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Win7-disk-I-O-error-can-t-log-in/m-p/1926317/highlight/true#M185640)

#### Additional Information:

We also tried running CrystalDiskInfo in the case that it might shed more light on the computer's hard drive itself. The info may not be pertinent, but here is a screenshot of all the information:

[image: Crystal Disk Info]

And the text copied from the program:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskInfo 6.0.4 (C) 2008-2013 hiyohiyo
                                Crystal Dew World : http://crystalmark.info/
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    OS : Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 [6.1 Build 7601] (x86)
  Date : 2013/12/12 23:45:37

-- Controller Map ----------------------------------------------------------
 + Standard AHCI 1.0 Serial ATA Controller [ATA]
   + ATA Channel 0 (0)
     - Hitachi HTS547575A9E384 ATA Device
   + ATA Channel 2 (2)
     - Slimtype DVD A  DS8A8SH ATA Device

-- Disk List ---------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) Hitachi HTS547575A9E384 : 750.1 GB [0/0/0, pd1]

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) Hitachi HTS547575A9E384
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : Hitachi HTS547575A9E384
        Firmware : JE4OA60A
   Serial Number : J2540059CTU6JE
       Disk Size : 750.1 GB (8.4/137.4/750.1/750.1)
     Buffer Size : 8192 KB
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 1465149168
   Rotation Rate : 5400 RPM
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ATA8-ACS
   Minor Version : ATA8-ACS version 6
   Transfer Mode : ---- | SATA/300
  Power On Hours : 6447 hours
  Power On Count : 685 count
     Temparature : 36 C (96 F)
   Health Status : Good
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, 48bit LBA, NCQ
       APM Level : 4080h [ON]
       AAM Level : ----

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 100 100 _62 000000000000 Read Error Rate
02 100 100 _40 000000000000 Throughput Performance
03 176 176 _33 000A00000001 Spin-Up Time
04 100 100 __0 0000000002FB Start/Stop Count
05 100 100 __5 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 100 100 _67 000000000000 Seek Error Rate
08 100 100 _40 000000000000 Seek Time Performance
09 _86 _86 __0 00000000192F Power-On Hours
0A 100 100 _60 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0C 100 100 __0 0000000002AD Power Cycle Count
BF 100 100 __0 000000010000 G-Sense Error Rate
C0 100 100 __0 000000000013 Power-off Retract Count
C1 _97 _97 __0 00000000968E Load/Unload Cycle Count
C2 166 166 __0 0032000F0024 Temperature
C4 100 100 __0 000000000000 Reallocation Event Count
C5 100 100 __0 000000000000 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 100 100 __0 000000000000 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
DF 100 100 __0 000000000000 Load/Unload Retry Count

-- IDENTIFY_DEVICE ---------------------------------------------------------
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
000: 045A 3FFF C837 0010 0000 0000 003F 0000 0000 0000
010: 2020 2020 2020 4A32 3534 3030 3539 4354 5536 4A45
020: 0003 4000 0004 4A45 344F 4136 3041 4869 7461 6368
030: 6920 4854 5335 3437 3537 3541 3945 3338 3420 2020
040: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 8010 4000 2F00
050: 4000 0200 0200 0007 3FFF 0010 003F FC10 00FB 0110
060: FFFF 0FFF 0000 0007 0003 0078 0078 0078 0078 0000
070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 001F 1706 0000 005E 0040
080: 01FC 0028 746B 7D69 6163 7469 BC49 6163 207F 0066
090: 0067 4080 FFFE 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
100: 66F0 5754 0000 0000 0000 0000 6003 826C 5000 CCA6
110: DFCB 478B 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 4018
120: 4018 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0029 000B
130: 0000 0000 2182 1CF1 FA00 0000 4000 0400 0108 0000
140: 0000 0606 0405 0406 0604 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
150: 0000 0000 3433 4436 0000 2904 0000 5DAD 2518 8000
160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0003 0000
170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 003D 0000 0000 4000
210: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1518 0000 0000
220: 0000 0000 101F 0021 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
230: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 03E0 0000 0000 0000 0000
240: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
250: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 FEA5

-- SMART_READ_DATA ---------------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 10 00 01 0B 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 05
010: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 07 00 B0 B0 01
020: 00 00 00 0A 00 00 04 12 00 64 64 FB 02 00 00 00
030: 00 00 05 33 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 0B
040: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 05 00 64 64 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 12 00 56 56 2F 19 00 00 00
060: 00 00 0A 13 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 32
070: 00 64 64 AD 02 00 00 00 00 00 BF 0A 00 64 64 00
080: 00 01 00 00 00 00 C0 32 00 64 64 13 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 C1 12 00 61 61 8E 96 00 00 00 00 00 C2 02
0A0: 00 A6 A6 24 00 0F 00 32 00 00 C4 32 00 64 64 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C5 22 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C6 08 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 0A
0D0: 00 C8 C8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DF 0A 00 64 64 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2D 00 01 5B
170: 03 00 01 00 02 CC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A8

-- SMART_READ_THRESHOLD ----------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 10 00 01 3E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 28
010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 21 00 00 00 00
020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
030: 00 00 05 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 43
040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 28 00 00 00 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
060: 00 00 0A 3C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00
070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BF 00 00 00 00 00
080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 C1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C2 00
0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C4 00 00 00 00 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 00
0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DF 00 00 00 00 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 89
```

**Note**: I will update the question with a log file from Skype when I have one. Till then we have to wait for a crash as it can't be reproduced and we only just enabled logging.

Comment: run chkdsk /F to detect and repair NTFS issues. Does this fix it?

Comment: I assume you _have_ contacted Skype customer support as instructed in the message. What did they say?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do when there is an I/O problem, is to run a thorough disk check, including a scan for bad sectors.

Answer (score 0):

There are more strange behaviors.
Something is wrong with Skype.

Check this fresh posts:

http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Skype-crashes-at-startup/m-p/2356663

http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/SINCE-1-HOUR-SKYPE-ACTS-RETARDED-uses-100-CPU/m-p/2356327

Possible solution:

Try to uninstall the currently installed version and install the previous 6.9.0.106 version using this msi-installer:

http://download.skype.com/msi/SkypeSetup_6.9.0.106.msi

After installing this version, make sure to disable the Automatic updates:

Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Automatic updates ->Turn off automatic updates